# Add virtual folder to Azure Web App

Tags: powershell, azure, octopus-deploy

I want to automate my deployment to Azure Web App.
I am using Octopus Deploy to deploy my app to a Azure Web App into a sub-folder based on my git-branch.

This works.

The problem is, that I need to add that folder to the list of virtual directories in the Application Settings of the Web App and I also have to mark it as an application.

How can I do this?
I can use anything that is possible with PowerShell.

P.S. I found this old thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/990f41fd-f8b6-43a0-b942-cef0308120b2/add-virtual-application-and-directory-to-an-azure-website-using-powershell?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview, but this no longer seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into the Azure Resource Manager - https://resources.azure.com - if you drill down to an existing Web App you can view REST & PowerShell commands for managing resources.  In the Web App JSON, you'll find a section for Virtual Applications:

```
"virtualApplications": [
  {
    "virtualPath": "/",
    "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
    "preloadEnabled": true,
    "virtualDirectories": null
  }
],
```

Since you are using Azure PowerShell, after `Get-AzureSubscription`, you should be able to do something like:

```
# PowerShell equivalent script
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager

# GET web
Get-AzureResource -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourWebApp/web -OutputObjectFormat New -ApiVersion 2015-08-01

# SET web
$PropertiesObject = @{
    #Property = value;
}

Set-AzureResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourWebApp/web -OutputObjectFormat New -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. Are there samples available that include the authentication part? I actually did manage to get it to work last night but the authentication is a nightmare. I had to create a WAAD Web App and assign it rights to the resource group. I am running in an Octopus Deploy context where the authentication is already done - `Get-AzureSubscription` returns my subscription without the need for me to do any authentication. Can I somehow reuse this existing authentication for the Azure Resource Manager?

Comment: You should be able to follow up with Azure PowerShell commands - added an example to the answer. The REST based Authentication example is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx

Comment: OK, so the code from the Link I put in my question is actually supposed to still work. I am getting a FileNotFound exception on the call to `Switch-AzureMode`, but only after the deprecation warning. I thought this was due to the deprecation. But must be something else then. I should check with the Octopus Deploy team then.

Comment: I was able to get it to work from within Octodeploy. With "work" I mean that it is now throwing an ARM exception. And it says: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is not present or provided in an invalid format. It looks like it isn't using the authentication for the "normal" Azure Powershell commands. Any idea on how to force ARM to use that authentication?

Comment: I think I found my answer: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/ This post says that the ARM API doesn't support management certificates, but that's exactly the approach that Octopus Deploy is using. So, I guess, I have to go the route of the WAAD App :-(

Comment: Thanks for the detailed follow-up, we are looking at various deploy solutions now.